# How to duplicate database with Users to permanent database in Firbase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I create an app with an authentification form and database based on the Firebase. The question - "Is it possible to duplicate data with authenticated users into a permanent database somehow?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking about two products (Firebase Authentication, and Firebase Realtime Database) and the answer is quite different for each of these.

For **Firebase Authentication** you can export the users from one project, and import them in the other project by either using the Firebase CLI (see [`auth:export` and `auth:import`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) or the Firebase Admin SDK (see [list users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and [import users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users)).

For the **Firebase Realtime Database** you can export any data and import it anywhere else using its [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). Alternatively, if you want to duplicate the entire database, you can take one of the [automated backups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups) that Firebase can make for you, and import that into the other project in the [database panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/firevotes/database/_/data) of your Firebase console.